# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer transform rendering speed

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am trying to get the pitch from CMMotion's attitude and make AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer transform with pitch angle using CATransform3D. Something like this:

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
float zDistance = 850;
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -zDistance;
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, -_pitch, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0);    
[_videoPreviewLayer setTransform:transform];
```

However, the transformed AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is so slow and it takes around 10 seconds to be transformed. Is there any suggestion to improve the preview layer with 3D transformation more smooth?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How frequently are you applying these new rotation and scaling transforms? There is overhead with setting up implicit animations, so if you are constantly changing the animation target, that could lead to the slowdown you're seeing. If you're doing this more than ten times per second, you may want to disable implicit animations for rotation and scaling on your layer.